# Correct Display configuration. Errors while trying to arrange displays

Tags: 12.04, display, monitor

I am trying to set up my tv with my laptop trough a VGA cable. The display application in Ubuntu throws a lot of errors to me and I have given up in trying to do it myself.

I try to apply the 1920 1080 display.

> The selected configuration for displays could not be applied
>
> Requested size (3200, 1080) exceeds 3D hardware limit (2048, 2048).
>   You must either rearrange the displays so that they fit within a
>   (2048, 2048) square or select the Ubuntu 2D session at login.

And Also this:

> Failed to apply configuration: %s
>
> GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gnome_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code3:
>   Requested size (3200, 1080) exceeds 3D hardware limit (2048, 2048).
>   You must either rearrange the displays so that they fit within a
>   (2048, 2048) square or select the Ubuntu 2D session at login.

Please Help.

@Leozitop

1. No I don't see anything when connected to 1920 1080 because the setup fails before actually applying.
2. Yes there are other resolutions which do work. I believe the problem has something to do with the rotation it is set up. My Ubuntu Display application has only clockwise and counterclockwise options for the TV display. I really don't know why this is happening.
3. Basic procedure: Plug in cable, did not get the resolution I wanted. Changed settings, applied them. Re-peat until desired display is shown. I'm not a computer illiterate, really it baffles me that this is happening.
4. Output of `xrandr`:

   david@LapUbuntu:~$ xrandr
   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1880 x 800, maximum 4096 x 4096
   LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
      1280x800       60.0*+
      1024x768       60.0
      800x600        60.3     56.2
      640x480        59.9
   VGA1 connected 600x800+1280+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
      1920x1080      60.0 +
      1280x1024      60.0
      1360x768       60.0
      1280x720       60.0
      1024x768       60.0
      800x600        60.3* 
      640x480        60.0
   TV1 unknown connection (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
      848x480        59.9 +
      640x480        59.9 +
      1024x768       59.9
      800x600        59.9

Note that VGA says left and indeed it is, but no other option was available in the display. Also, note the TV1 unknown connection which I have no idea what it is.

Note, also, that this has nothing to do with the display since W7 on the computer works fine and since while boot up, and also, **before starting session in ubuntu the rotation is normal**.

I'll also mention that I HAVE re-installed Ubuntu since I had posted this question from a Live CD of 12.04 LTS. And that before the posting of the question also using 12.04 before another backup that I had to do, the VGA setup was fine without any problems.

Comment: 1. Can you see any image on your TV at all? 2. Do you have problems only with that resolution setting or any? 3. Can you tell us how you are trying to set up the resolution? Step by step, if applicable; 4. What is the output for the command `xrandr`?

Comment: looks like your graphics card doesn't have enough video memory to maintain two hd displays in a 3d environment. How much does it have ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem has anything to do with the rotation of the screen. If you think so because of the word *"inverted"* on the output from `xrandr`, don't worry. That word is always there even if your setup is not inverted.

I believe you are getting that error because your hardware doesn't support Unity 3D at that resolution. If my guess is correct, you will need to switch to Unity 2D, which is less demanding in terms of graphics.

In order to do that, go to the login screen (the screen before you start the session), click on the Ubuntu icon to the right of your username and select *Ubuntu 2D*. Then log in and try to set the desired resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I resolved it by using ARandR.  There is a nice little GUI interface that you can find by searching for the application.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error (exceeds 3D hardware limit (2048, 2048)) also with an old Toshiba with Linux Mint. I had a laptop with a screen 1280x800 and a monitor 1980x1080. I Solved the problem by placing the displays on top of each other. Wat makes the total square 1980 x (1080+800).

It's a bit akward that I have to move my mouse up to get on the monitor, but it works with hardware 3D, without it also works on Linux Mint, but each command takes about 15 seconds, so the system nearly is stopped.

Good luck.